# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpytools' while using reticulate library

Tags: r, reticulate

Hi this is my first stackoverflow question so sorry in advance for any mistakes. I am trying to start playing with R `reticulate` library. I have installed the package, and tried to import `os` Python module. Everything seemed to be ok, but then while I start typing for example `os$listdir` R throws this error: `Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpytools'`. Here is my entire code:

```
install.packages("reticulate")
library(reticulate)
os <- import("os")
os$listdir("")
```

Here is my output of `py_config()` :

```
python:         C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\python.exe
libpython:      C:/PROGRA~3/ANACON~1/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1
version:        3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.12.1
os:             C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\lib\os.py
```

and `py_available(TRUE)` returns `TRUE`...

Please write me if there is any additional info needed.

Comment: Could you share the result of `py_config()`? Do you get error when this line executes `os <- import("os")`? Any errors during reticulate installation or library loading?

Comment: in addition to `py_config()`, what is the result of `py_available(TRUE)`?

Comment: I have edited my post by adding outputs which you asked for. I don't get any errors while installation or loading the library, or even when I run the `os <- import("os")` line. But when I start to use any of the `os` module commands it throws the error. What is unexpected for me is that it throws it while I start writing `os$listdir`.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that I am on my work computer, and  there may be some issues because of the firewall or because I don't have admin status. Yesterday I installed `reticulate` on my personal computer, where I have the same Python and Anaconda version and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved?  I'm running into the same problem.  Works for personal computer, but not for work computer.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **you need to use RStudio version 1.2 or higher, currently only available as a [preview release](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/), to get experimental `reticulate` support**.

Support for `reticulate` in current RStudio stable releases (<1.2) is pretty flaky and any hope of using RStudio <1.2 as a Python IDE falls apart as soon as you try to work with imported modules. This is mentioned as an [offhand comment](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/r_markdown.html) in the `reticulate` docs:

> Note that the RStudio v1.2 preview release includes support for using reticulate to execute Python chunks within R Notebooks. See the [RStudio IDE Tools for reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/rstudio_ide.html) article for additional details.

Your code doesn't throw an error in RStudio 1.2:

```
> library(reticulate)
> os <- import("os")
> os$listdir()
 [1] ".Rhistory"         ".Rproj.user"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this resolved for my work computer.  I'm not sure if it's the reason, but I noticed that my R.exe & python.exe were saved in different driver names. One in C: & the other in X:.  So, what I did was uninstall R & python then saved them both into the same driver.  This is how I resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in windows and what helped me was to manually add the path to reticulate python to the PYTHONPATH ennvironment variable.

In R you get the path to reticulate python with:

```
paste0(system.file(package = "reticulate"),"/python")
```

Create the PYTHONPATH environment variable in the windows system environment variable settings if it doesnt exist. Add the result from the command above to the PYTHONPATH ennvironment variable path. Save and restart RStudio.