# Call R object from Python with r. in a Quarto document

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, reticulate, quarto

I try to call an R object from Python inside a Quarto document:

````
---
title: "pandas"
format: html
jupyter: python3
---

```{r}
data("penguins", package = "palmerpenguins")
```

```{python}
penguins=r.penguins
penguins
```
````

When I execute the chunks one by one in RStudio, everything is okay:

```
> data("penguins", package = "palmerpenguins")
> reticulate::repl_python() # automatically executed by RStudio
Python 3.10.4 (/Users/.../3.10.4/bin/python3.10)
Reticulate 1.24 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
Enter 'exit' or 'quit' to exit the REPL and return to R.
>>> penguins=r.penguins
>>> penguins
       species     island  bill_length_mm  ...  body_mass_g     sex  year
0       Adelie  Torgersen            39.1  ...         3750    male  2007
1       Adelie  Torgersen            39.5  ...         3800  female  2007
...
```

However, when I try to render this document, it errors this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Python chunk
----> 2 penguins=r.penguins
      3 penguins

NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

According to [RMarkdown documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/r_markdown.html#calling-r-from-python), nothing else is required (so no e.g. `rpy2`).

I try to add `library(reticulate)` or `reticulate::repl_python()` in the R chunk but it doesn't solve the issue.

Note: I'm aware of an [old unanswered similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747585/reticulate-python-chunk-saying-r-genrates-nameerror) for RMarkdown.

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't use Quarto, but ran your code (saved as `test-reticulate.Rmd` after replacing `penguins` with `mtcars`) and didn't get any error messages by rendering.

I used the following code to render the document: `library(rmarkdown); render("test-reticulate.Rmd")`.

My platform from `sessionInfo()` and `sys.version`, respectively. R: `R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10), Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit), Running under: Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03`; Python: `'3.10.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2022, 17:51:59) [GCC 10.3.0]'`.
R package versions: `reticulate_1.24 rmarkdown_2.13`.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, I found a 'trick' that made it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quarto have two engines for render, knitr and jupyter.A related document is [here](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html#engine-binding).

If we use:

````
---
title: "pandas"
format: html
---

```{r}
data("penguins", package = "palmerpenguins")
```

```{python}
penguins=r.penguins
penguins
```
````

The engine will be knitr. And while render, knitr will use [`reticulate`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/)(R Interface to Python) to run python code chunk. In this process, knitr will do some magic things to convert the form like `r.penguins` to the form of `reticulate`. So the document will be successfully rendered. In other words, knitr made some adaptations to let us could easily run python code chunk with `reticulate`, and if we don't use knitr engine, we can't use the form like `r.penguins`.

> Quarto use r run all code chunks (auto use r package `reticulate` to run python chunks) when it uses knitr engine.

> And Quarto use python to run all code chunks when it uses jupyter (jupyter: python3) engine. If we want run r code, we must use module (such as rpy2) in python chunk (not r chunk, codes in r chunk will not be run).

> We can also use r to run all code chunks by setting `jupyter: ir` (if we have installed IRkernel).But codes in python chunk will not be run. We must use package (such as reticulate) in r chunk to run python code.

This is my understanding. My English is not good, so if some sentence made you puzzled, we could discuss further.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

I have no explanation, but removing the line `jupyter: python3` in the YAML solved my issue.